# How to simulate DataRow Merge and build a 2D DataRow array?

Tags: c#, recursion, datatable, dataset, datarow

I'm trying to make a simple DataRow Merge, but somehow I don't get right datas back.

I want to build a 2D DataRow array

This is a simple dataSet definition with dataTables and dataRelations and filled dataRows.

> ```
>         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
> ```

```
        ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { 
            new DataTable("Person"),
            new DataTable("Car"),
            new DataTable("Color"),
            new DataTable("RGB"),
            new DataTable("Bicycle")
        });
        ds.Tables["Person"].Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("FName", typeof(string))
        });
        ds.Tables["Car"].Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("PersonId", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("CType", typeof(string))
        });
        ds.Tables["Color"].Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("CarId", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ColorName", typeof(string))
        });
        ds.Tables["RGB"].Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ColorId", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("HEX", typeof(string))
        });
        ds.Tables["Bicycle"].Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("PersonId", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Age", typeof(string))
        });
        ds.Tables["Person"].ChildRelations.Add(new DataRelation("PersonCar", ds.Tables["Person"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["Car"].Columns["PersonId"]));
        ds.Tables["Car"].ChildRelations.Add(new DataRelation("CarColor", ds.Tables["Car"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["Color"].Columns["CarId"]));
        ds.Tables["Color"].ChildRelations.Add(new DataRelation("ColorRGB", ds.Tables["Color"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["RGB"].Columns["ColorId"]));
        ds.Tables["Person"].ChildRelations.Add(new DataRelation("PersonBicycle", ds.Tables["Person"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["Bicycle"].Columns["PersonId"]));

        ds.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(0, "John");
        ds.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(1, "Jenny");
        ds.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(2, "Adam");

        ds.Tables["Car"].Rows.Add(0, 0, "Renault");
        ds.Tables["Car"].Rows.Add(1, 0, "Jeep");
        ds.Tables["Car"].Rows.Add(2, 1, "Subaru");
        ds.Tables["Car"].Rows.Add(3, 2, "Daewoo");

        ds.Tables["Color"].Rows.Add(0, 0, "Red");
        ds.Tables["Color"].Rows.Add(1, 1, "Black1");
        ds.Tables["Color"].Rows.Add(2, 1, "Black2");
        ds.Tables["Color"].Rows.Add(3, 1, "Black3");
        ds.Tables["Color"].Rows.Add(4, 2, "Green");
        ds.Tables["Color"].Rows.Add(5, 3, "Blue");

        ds.Tables["RGB"].Rows.Add(0, 1, "GREEN RGB1");
        ds.Tables["RGB"].Rows.Add(1, 1, "GREEN RGB2");

        ds.Tables["Bicycle"].Rows.Add(2, 0, "Mount.");
```

I want to get a 2D DataRow array with following results:

> ```
>         John, Renault, Red
>         John, Jeep, Black1, GREEN RGB1
>         John, Jeep, Black1, GREEN RGB2
>         John, Jeep, Black2
>         John, Jeep, Black3          
>         John, Mount.
>         Jenny, Subaru, Green
>         ....
> ```

I don't want to use DataTable.Merge! So how to write a recursive function that populates the 2D array.

> List of List of DataRows

results?

It's very urgently, so every king of help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with traversing the dataset? But I can´t help you. Regards.